# Searching features implementation in django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

How do i query a database in django with multiple keywords

I have a Job model having the class such that

```
class Job(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to query the jobs_job database to implement the search features such that

```
def search(request):
 if request.method == "GET":
   search_terms = request.GET['title']
   search_terms = search_terms.split(',')

   jobs = Job.objects.filter(title__contains=search_terms[0])
```

The problem is I only can pass one item to the `contains` method,

How do I search using multiple words to the Job model title attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can do

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
      search_terms = request.GET['title'] 
      search_terms = search_terms.split(',')
      #get rid of duplicates
      search_terms = set(search_terms)
      queryargs = [Q(title__contains=i) for i in search_terms]
      jobs = Job.objects.filter(*queryargs)
```

Comment: please see my edit, I've used your names for the variables and cleared things up according to your separator `,`

Answer (score 1):

Use `django.db.models.Q` objects. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
   if request.method == "GET":
       search_terms = request.GET['title']
       search_filter = Q()
       for term in search_terms.split(','):
            search_filter |= Q(title__contains=term)

       jobs = Job.objects.filter(search_filter)
```

This will search for any of the terms (OR), to search for all terms (AND) use `search_filter &= Q(title__contains=term)` instead.